# facebook like notifications in React JS and redux with count on notifications icon?

Tags: reactjs, notifications, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I am developing React based web application. I want to show notifications to user like whenever user receives a friend request and when user confirms his/her friend request etc.

I want to implement a notification system with notifications count exactly like how Facebook has today. 
When user clicks on notification icon it should show list of notifications in the Dropdown. I Dono how to implement this and where to start.

Right now, I have add friend functionality when user clicks on + icon marked with red color a friend request will be sent to recipient [image: add friend image] I am making a call to backed and sending add friend request information as like below

```
  AddFriend(loginId){
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('/');
let friendId = params[3];
let data = {}
data.loginId = loginId;
data.friendId = friendId;
this.props.submitFriendRequest(data)
```

}

In DB I am storing as

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5d883c66bd54040c4808af"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-01-16T05:06:04.997Z"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-01-16T05:06:04.997Z"), "requester" : "5a4a0c0c13aa6120980ab532", "recipient" : "5a4d033a2d2c6b2264bf8120", "status" : 1, "__v" : 0 }
```

Now I want to show a notification to recipient like you have received a friend request from xxx in notification with count like in the picture [image: notification icon with drop down]

I am using Reactjs, redux, material UI, Node.js, Mongodb. Any suggestions on where to start to display notifications? Is there any reactjs npm module for this? I am not expecting the complete code but moreover looking for suggestions. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can provide your attempts. But if you didn't attempt yet. I guess the only way is establishing a `socket` connection between your client and server.

You are using `redux` and `node.js`. Possibly you can use socket.io for the backend socket connections, and you can use [`redux-socket.io`](https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io) for establishing the socket connection to your backend `socket.io` server.

https://github.com/ItsMrAkhil/Anonymous-Chat here is my usage of the same stack that you're using. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I updated my question with additional information. Yours looks like a chat functionality right?

Comment: Yes. It's kind of chat functionality. But it involves everything that you need. Basically, the server should send a piece of information to its socket connections. And client should receive that information.

Comment: Ok great. Does this includes notifications functionality as well?

Comment: Look, I gave you the demo. It just shows the message right after one sends the message. In your case, you have to increase the notifications number. But I can't spend the time to create exact requirements for yours.

Comment: I can do that myself if I get an idea. I was confused on how chat helps notifications. Let me take a look at your code. Thanks